# Does the Cauchy problem $x'=\operatorname{sgn}(t), x(0)=0$ have a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Check if Cauchy's Problem has a solution:
$$ x'=\operatorname{sgn}(t), x(0)=0 $$

My solution:
by definition of the $\operatorname{sgn}$ fuction
$$ x'=1 \Rightarrow x(t)=t+C_1 $$
$$ x'=-1 \Rightarrow x(t) = -t + C_2 $$
The solution doesn't exist because of lack of continuity.

However I'm not sure if it's right solution.

Comment: A solution on what interval? If this is $t\ge0$ and your initial condition is $x(0)=0$, then the solution is $x(t)=0$, $t\ge0$.

Comment: In the exercise i don't have any interval. So $t \in R $ I guess.

Comment: Generally speaking, the solution is thought of as $x(t)=|t|+C,$ though what happens at the origin is sometimes glossed over since $|t|$ is not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @KBS this is inhomogeneous. the solution would be $x(t) = t$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Ah yeah, sorry, I read $\mathrm{sgn}(x(t))$. Nevermind, then.